# Is there a way to efficiently join two tables with keys stored on a list format

Tags: r, join, dplyr, merge, tibble

Example of code to illustrate my issue here.

```
table_A <- tibble(A1 = c("a", "a/b"), A2 = seq(1,2))
table_A <- table_A %>% mutate(A1 = str_split(A1, "/"))

table_B <- tibble(A1 = c("a","b"), B1 = c("apple", "bananas"))

#does not work
#left_join(table_A, table_B)
```

The desired result would be to have a new B1 column with
c("apple") and c("apple", "bananas") but obviously this code does not work. In practice the lists range from no key to 5 keys long.
Happy to take any suggestions, maybe there is a way to re-frame the data or th problem to solve it elegantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `unnest` the `list` column before doing the join

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
table_A %>% 
    unnest(A1) %>%
    left_join(table_B)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  A1       A2 B1     
  <chr> <int> <chr>  
1 a         1 apple  
2 a         2 apple  
3 b         2 bananas
```

---

Or another option is to use `separate_rows` instead of `strsplit` and then do the join

```
table_A %>% 
    separate_rows(A1, sep="/") %>%
    left_join(table_B)
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option

```
> rev(setDT(table_A)[, .(A1 = unlist(A1)), A2])[setDT(table_B), on = .(A1)]
   A1 A2      B1
1:  a  1   apple
2:  a  2   apple
3:  b  2 bananas
```

Answer (score 1):

@akrun : thanks for your reply, that's what I was looking for!

To get exactly the expected result under table_C I simply added a chop line to your suggestion:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
table_A <- tibble(A1 = c("a", "a/b"), A2 = seq(1,2))
table_B <- tibble(A1 = c("a","b"), B1 = c("apple", "bananas"))

table_C <- table_A %>% 
    separate_rows(A1, sep="/") %>%
    left_join(table_B) %>% 
    chop(c(A1,B1))

table_C
```